# how to show some text on mouseover extjs grid row

Tags: grid, extjs4, hover, row, mouseover

I am usig extjs 4.1. I went through a lot of threads explaining about tooltip on mouseover with dataview. However I just need to show some text like "double click on this row" on mouseover on any row of the grid... I have this function so far from another thread... but it's not working inside the grid

```
function renderTip(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store) {
                metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
                return value;
        };
```

UPDATE - This is my grid

```
Ext.define('GridViewApp.view.GridViewApp', {
alias: 'widget.gridviewapp',
width: 800,
title: 'My Grid Panel',
grid: null,
store: null,
layout: {
    type: 'anchor'
},
constructor: function () {

    this.callParent(arguments);

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

        storeId: 'myData',
        scope: this,
        fields: [
        { name: 'Q1', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Q2', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Q3', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Q4', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Q5', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Improvements', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Comments', type: 'string' }
        ],

        sorters: [
            {
                //property: 'myData',
                direct: 'ASC'
            }
         ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            scope: this,
            url: 'GridView/writeRecord',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'myTable',
                idProperty: 'ID'

                }
        } 
    });

    store.load();   
    this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'GridView App',
        store: this.store,
        columns: [
            {header: 'Q1', width: 100,
        sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q1'
                    },
        { header: 'Q2', width: 100,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q2'
        },
        { header: 'Q3', width: 100,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q3'
        },
                    { header: 'Q4', width: 100,
                        sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q4'
                    },
                    { header: 'Improvements', width: 200,
                        sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Improvements'
                    },
                    { header: 'Comments', width: 200,
                        sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Comments'
                    }
    ],
        stripeRows: true,
        width: 800,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    this.add(this.grid);
    this.grid.getView().getEl().set({ 'data-qtip': 'Double click me' });
}
});
```

UPDATE - WORKING SOLUTION 
Add this to your listener on grid and it works

```
 itemmouseenter: function (view, record, item) {
                        Ext.fly(item).set({ 'data-qtip': 'Hello' });
                    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this renderer is attached as each column renderer, tip should work. Verify if you have `Ext.QuickTips.init()` call somewhere in the code. Bellow is what I think is easier way to attach global tooltip to grid by attaching it to view.

```
grid.getView().getEl().set({ 'data-qtip': 'Double click me' });
Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/GCRA5/

Comment: Thanks Lolo... I tried this at the end of my grid but app is crashing... the problem is I use a constructor so not sure where should I put ext.quicktip.init()... do I have include this if I have 'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager'?

Comment: Actually `Ext.QuickTips` is an alias to `Ext.tip.QuickTipManager`. I don't know why app is crashing without code, can you send it?

Comment: sure... it says Cannot call method 'set' of undefined on my debugger

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'add'` error, because `GridViewApp.view.GridViewApp` is not extending anything, but after adding `extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport'` it's working.

Comment: I tried doing that too... it still says cannot call method set... could you please show me a working copy

Comment: Thanks Lolo... you helped me solve this problem... I have updated my post with an answer for others with similar problem